# C++/SDL - Rectangle Coordinates Mapping

Tags: c++, mapping, coordinates

I am working on a 2D game using SDL. Recently I implemented various functions that put objects (and their rectangles) into motion, but encountered performance issues that are most likely caused by inefficient mapping of rectangle coordinates. Please see below:

2D coordinates of the rectangle are stored in an integer array whenever move() is called. For example, coordinate[0] is the first point on the x axis and coordinate[1] is the last point on the x axis. Coordinates [2] and [3] work for points on the y axis.

The map() function takes the coordinates of a rectangle and stores them in static std::map (Status class). Each x and y pair is either 0 or 1, depending on whether a rectangle is present or not. Player's coordinates are not mapped.

When the player moves, the bool function collide() checks whether the player's rectangle is adjacent to another recantgle in a particular direction. If there is no rectangle blocking the way, the player is allowed to move.

Everything works well, but it seems like all these for loops in the map() function are very CPU-heavy. When rectangles are being moved on the screen, the program lags horribly. How can I map rectangle coordinates more efficiently?

```
void move(int x, int y) {
    dstRect.x = x;
    dstRect.y = y;

    coordinate[0] = dstRect.x;
    coordinate[1] = dstRect.x + dstRect.w;
    coordinate[2] = dstRect.y;
    coordinate[3] = dstRect.y + dstRect.h;
}

void map() {
    for (int x = coordinate[0]; x != coordinate[1]; x++) {
        for (int y = coordinate[2]; y != coordinate[3]; y++) {
            Status::map().insert(std::pair<std::vector<int>, int>({ x, y }, 1));
        }
    }
}

bool collide(DIRECTION direction) {
    if (direction == UP || direction == DOWN) {
        for (int x = texture.coordinate[0]; x != texture.coordinate[1]; x++) {
            if (direction == UP) {
                if (Status::map().find({ x, texture.coordinate[2] - 1 })->second == 1) { return true; }
            }
            if (direction == DOWN) {
                if (Status::map().find({ x, texture.coordinate[3] + 1 })->second == 1) { return true; }
            }
        }
    }
    if (direction == RIGHT || direction == LEFT) {
        for (int y = texture.coordinate[2]; y != texture.coordinate[3]; y++) {
            if (direction == RIGHT) {
                if (Status::map().find({ texture.coordinate[1] + 1, y })->second == 1) { return true; }
            }
            if (direction == LEFT) {
                if (Status::map().find({ texture.coordinate[0] - 1, y })->second == 1) { return true; }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void moveRight() {
    for (int i = 0; i < speed; i ++) {
        if (!collide(RIGHT)) {
            int x = texture.dstRect.x + 1;
            int y = texture.dstRect.y;
            texture.move(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider mapping your state using an single `vector` where coordinates each correspond to a unique index, such as `index = x + y * width`. Edit : Actually, I thought your key was a `std::pair<int,int>` but I now see it also contains a `vector`. I don't understand what your `Status::map` represents or how it's laid out.

Comment: It seems like your map is a `std::map<std::vector<int>, int>` or something similar. So my original comment applies. You are creating new vectors every time you insert into your map. You need to iterate over vectors every time you want to compare then when searching through it. There is a lot of waste here that could easily explain your performance issues.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `struct Status{static std::map<std::vector<int>, int>& map() { static std::map<std::vector<int>, int> objectMap; return objectMap; }};` This is how Status::map() is laid out, so you are correct. I though mapping coordinates this way is a good idea so I can store coordinates in the vector {x,y} and assign a number to that location, depending on whether a rectangle is present or not. 0 means no object, 1 impassable object, 2 bonus chest etc...

Comment: You need to start breaking up your 'world' into area's so you can quickly discount large numbers of object from consideration when you are performing operations. For example, break your world up into 4 quadrants, and assign the applicable objects to the appropriate bucket. If more resolution is necessary, break each quadrant up into it's own set of quadrants, etc. This mechanism is called a quadtree and is uniquely applicable to your problem.

Comment: @Aumnayan I've heard of quadtree mechanism before but it seems difficult to implement.

Comment: @Chriss555888 Conceptually it's about as difficult as a B-Tree. Implementation wise, it will likely be cleaner then other ad-hoc organization you try to implement to do the same thing. Which will make your life easier as you implement more features in your application. The down side is yes, you have to implement the quadtree object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed @FrançoisAndrieux advice and created multidimensional vector for storing the coordinates.